# Incrementing in list comprehension

Tags: python

I want to increment my list by one for each iteration. For example in the sample code I created a list readers. Now readers contains all the rows of my CSV file. What I am trying to do is to start from first row , look if the condition is satisfied then iterate to the next row by increment the list by 1. Any idea how can I proceed with it ? Before print(row) I want to increment the list by 1 and look for some other conditions if they are satisfied or not.

```
for path in glob.glob("out.csv"):
    if path == "out1.csv": continue
    with open(path) as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh)
        readers = list(reader)
        for row in readers:
            if corner1 in row:
                if search_string in row:

                    if state0 in row:


                        print(row)
                        writer.writerow(row + [] + [row[2]])
                        break
```

Comment: Hint:  Python's `for` statement is a `foreach` statement; it will iterate over everything in the collection independent of index location.  The only way you can possibly get an indexable loop is with `while`, but you manage its state 100% on your own.  Additionally...I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to accomplish.  Are you looking to filter values out of your CSV output?  There's a *better* and *simpler* way to go about that...

Comment: In my csv output file I am trying to filter out all the rows and summarize whole data in a single row . Idea is to iterate through each row in the list and then write the unique values in a single line .

Comment: What do you mean by "increment the list"?  If you mean "append to the list", then your iteration will never end.  If you mean "move on to the next row", iteration already does that --- it's what iteration is _for_.